# How do I get a unit test to login to my Zend applicaion using PHPUnit

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I am trying to test my login controller, I have read through many posts, and tried what is shown in the ZF ref. guide as well, still having problems.

I'm also new to Zend and PHPUnit.

I set my CSRF to only be used in 'production', and am testing in 'development' (or 'testing') Env. to eliminate that hassle.

I have a field in my login form 'agency', and I think it may be hindering my progress (or not)...I am not sure really. It is a multi-select dropdown, normally populated with an array (from enum column in DB).

Here is the test I am trying to use, I am going to keep the commented out lines too, they show what I've tried, and/or would like to try. The method 'canLoginToApp' as it is will pass, but I know it's not logging in (or testing much either), and I'm not getting code coverage in the login action (or login form class either), and cannot assert that I have identity or anything else that should be there if I'm logged in. Also if I use the method above, test for login form it fails with a cannot query DOM exception.

Here is my test:

```
<?php
/**
 * Description of LoginControllerTest
 * @author rob
 */
class LoginControllerTest 
    extends ControllerTestCase
{
    protected $userModel;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->userModel = new Application_Model_Users();
    }

//    public function testIndexActionShouldContainLoginForm() {
//        $this->dispatch('/login');
//        $this->assertAction('index');
//        $this->assertQueryCount('form#loginForm', 1);
//    }

    public function testGetAGoodPage()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/');
        $this->assertResponseCode(302);
    }


    public function testCanLoginToApp()
    {   
                $this->request->setMethod('POST')
                ->setPost(array(
                    'agency'    => array('3'),
                    'username'  => 'rob',
                    'password'  => 'nonenone',
                ));
       $this->dispatch('/');

        $this->assertController('index');
        $this->assertAction('index');
        $this->dispatch('/login/index');
        $this->assertResponseCode(302);
       // $this->assertTrue($this->userModel->currentUserIdentity());
       // var_dump($this->users->currentUserIdentity());
        //$this->assertQueryContentContains('<span>', 'User Name: rob');
                $data = $this->getResponse();
        //var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

My app always takes you to '/login' if your not logged in already (or more specifically, if 'Zend_Auth::getInstance != hasIdentity() ). I would like to assert that it does 'hasIdentity' in the test. I can only get a '302' found code on any page I get with testing as well, but in phpfirebug I get a 200. I think though, that is because of (zend's) routing(?)

Messing with this last night, I added the $data=getResponse() and dumped it (var_dump commented out now), the var_dump kept going on, and on, and on. It looked like it was rolling through the entire application...wierd :) 
Here is a small snippet of that:

```
  ["_moduleControllerDirectoryName":protected]=>
                      string(11) "controllers"
                      ["_plugins":protected]=>
                      object(Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker)#90 (3) {
                        ["_plugins":protected]=>
                        array(0) {
                        }
                        ["_request":protected]=>
                        object(Zend_Controller_Request_HttpTestCase)#76 (18) {
                          ["_headers":protected]=>
                          array(0) {
                          }
                          ["_method":protected]=>
                          string(4) "POST"
                          ["_rawBody":protected]=>
                          NULL
                          ["_validMethodTypes":protected]=>
                          array(6) {
                            [0]=>
                            string(6) "DELETE"
                            [1]=>
                            string(3) "GET"
                            [2]=>
                            string(4) "HEAD"
                            [3]=>
                            string(7) "OPTIONS"
                            [4]=>
                            string(4) "POST"
                            [5]=>
                            string(3) "PUT"
                          }
                          ["_paramSources":protected]=>
                          array(2) {
                            [0]=>
                            string(4) "_GET"
                            [1]=>
                            string(5) "_POST"
                          }
                          ["_requestUri":protected]=>
                          string(12) "/login/index"
                          ["_baseUrl":protected]=>
                          string(0) ""
                          ["_basePath":protected]=>
                          NULL
                          ["_pathInfo":protected]=>
                          string(12) "/login/index"
                          ["_params":protected]=>
                          array(3) {
                            ["controller"]=>
                            string(5) "login"
                            ["action"]=>
                            string(5) "index"
                            ["module"]=>
                            string(7) "default"
                          }
                          ["_aliases":protected]=>
                          array(0) {
                          }
                          ["_dispatched":protected]=>
                          bool(true)
                          ["_module":protected]=>
                          string(7) "default"
                          ["_moduleKey":protected]=>
                          string(6) "module"
                          ["_controller":protected]=>
                          string(5) "login"
                          ["_controllerKey":protected]=>
                          string(10) "controller"
                          ["_action":protected]=>
                          string(5) "index"
                          ["_actionKey":protected]=>
                          string(6) "action"
                        }
                        ["_response":protected]=>
                        *RECURSION*
                      }
```

Here is the source view of the login page (as from the browser):

```
<h2>Login</h2>

<form id="login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/login"><dl class="zend_form">
<dt id="agency-label"><label for="agency" class="required">Agency:</label></dt>
<dd id="agency-element">
<select name="agency" id="agency">
    <option value="00003" label="Dev Agency">Dev Agency</option>
    <option value="00004" label="ISR">ISR</option>
</select></dd>
<dt id="username-label"><label for="username" class="required">Username:</label></dt>
<dd id="username-element">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" /></dd>
<dt id="password-label"><label for="password" class="required">Password:</label></dt>

<dd id="password-element">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" /></dd>
<dt id="login-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="login-element">
<input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" /></dd></dl></form></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The top portion of the page is just normal head meta tags (css, title, etc.).

Also in my 'Post' array, for 'agency' I have tried

```
3
00003
'3'
'00003'
'Dev Agency'
array('00003' => 'Dev Agency')
array('3')
array(3)
array(00003)
```

I've also tried $this->dispatch('/'), ('/login'), ('index') and maybe a couple others too.
I'm not sure it is super important to test my login really, but I'd like to be capable of doing it, and I'm thinking to test some of my code I need to be logged in, or at least get 'hasIdentity' = true from Zend_Auth, as I do a lot of checking for this in the app. This I prefer than to give a 'fake' Auth object from the test.

As a side, or extended question 'Does the zend framework do anything internally when in ENV 'testing' or is this completely my own environment done out of convention (of course available for me to use)? Does any part of the ZF pay attention to the environment for that matter (production, testing, development, staging)? I ask because I also tried some testing in the 'testing' env. thinking that the dispatch, or the router may behave a bit different in the testing env. (redirects, response, request, etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to tests you should be able to access Zend_Auth as you would normally and test it. E.g.

```
// after correct login there should be zend_auth identity setup 
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$this->assertTrue($auth->hasIdentity());
```

Comment: The issue that I am having first (I think), is that I am trying to login (set the auth storage w/ valid credentials) then assert that $auth->hasIdentity. I think one of my problems (and I'd need to do this anyway) is that my auth is in a controller still, I think I need to move it out to the domain in a model. I should make it a service to the app probably. Then it should be easier to set auth storage within a test(?) Still in early stages of dev on this one, already creating 'go back and fix' issues :)

Comment: @rhaag71. You can have a look at [my unit tests](https://github.com/marcinwol/houseshare/blob/appartments/tests/application/controllers/UserControllerTest.php) for login. Maybe it will give you some clues that will help you.

Comment: Thanks, very much! Very enlightening, I will have to take some time to look over the whole thing, but I see right away many clues/tips to help me move on with my own unit testing. I can also see that I am/was taking a hap-hazard (quick) approach (I know better), I need to change my perspective on my testing :) I should be learning to use TDD anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

The ENV 'testing' simply load the testing block in your application.ini with specific settings. For passing the test on the response code its kinda tricky, you need to return the redirect like explained [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7496)

```
return $this->_redirect("/");
```

And for executing your commented block of code you need to switch the request and make another one:

```
//[...]
$this->resetRequest();
$this->resetResponse();
$this->dispatch("/");
```

And then your assert code:

```
   $this->assertTrue($this->userModel->currentUserIdentity());
   var_dump($this->users->currentUserIdentity());
   $this->assertQueryContentContains('<span>', 'User Name: rob');
```

note: For checking the userIdentity you dont need to do another GET request, because the authentication storage (i suppose) is filled when you POST the data to the controller. However, it's your business to organize it in a better way

note 2: Instead of checking the response code, try use the assertRedirect method..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the link to the page about redirect issues. I added the resets (I've tried these earlier too, just forgot to mention in my post), but with no more success. Adding the 'return' to the redirect does not help assert a '200' either, although it may not be important yet. My auth does store in session, I'm using Zend_Auth and it's session storage, so your right about that; the data should be in session storage the 'currentUserIdentity' is just some extra user data and/or returns false if Zend_Auth hasIdentity is false as well. assertRedirect('/') fails too.

Comment: The code 200 of a response is not a redirect, is "OK"..which means "Good to go". The first parameter of assertRedirect() is not the location of the redirect but the message, so you need just to do assertRedirect() without parameters and if you want to check the location of the redirect use assertRedirectTo("/");

Comment: Thanks, that helps me make sense of the assertRedirect. I will have to get back after some more attempts.